# exam document class: different points for different student groups

Tags: exam

In the `exam` class, is there a way to have different points for different groups of students? In particular, what I want to do is have:

- Regular problems that are required for *all* students
- Additional problems that are only required for graduate students

I'd like to be able to automatically generate:

- Separate totals at the start of the exam ("100 total points for undergraduates, 125 total points for graduate students"), and
- Separate totals for questions that have multiple subparts, some for undergrads and some for graduate students ("8 points for undergraduates, 10 points for graduate students").

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: If you can do both version with exam class, then you can install a switch.  I'm fond of plain TeX \newif{\ifmyflag} \myflagtrue \myflagfalse \ifmyflag \else \fi.  Others prefer the ifthenelse package.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but I don't want to switch back and forth between the two types of students. I want one exam that displays both sets of points. (Both undergrads and grads are in the same class, same room -- I just want one version of the exam.)

Comment: Ah, you want two sets of points!  I would try to emulate the existing point system with new macros and try to figure out how to place them where them belong.  If there is a convenient macro in the exam class source code you could replace it using \let\macro=\mymacro.  Truth is, exam class is for beginners.  Maybe it's time to lose the training wheels.

Comment: OK in that case I'll probably skip it. Not worth the hassle in this case.